# How to get most precise location using google maps Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to get users current location using google maps API but even after I turn on GPS I am not able to get the current location most precisely although I don't get any error. First, I am checking for permissions then I am checking is GPS enabled and after that showing a marker at the current location

My Code

```
    public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 9001;
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR_CODE = 9002;
    public static final String TAG = "MyTag";
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mLocationClient;

    Toolbar toolbar;

    String LatitudeBack;
    String LongitudeBack;


    Double LATITUDE,LONGITUDE;
    private double Delhi_LAT = 28.630597;
    private double Delhi_LONG= 77.218978;


    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


        isServicesOk();

        mLocationClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment= (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        assert supportMapFragment != null;
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }

    private void initGoogleMap() {

        if(isServicesOk()){
            if (isGPSEnabled()) {
                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();

                    getCurrentLocation();
                } else {
                    requestLocationPermission();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void gotoLocation(double lat,double lng){

        LatLng latLng=new LatLng(lat,lng);

        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,DEFAULT_ZOOM);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    private boolean checkLocationPermission() {

        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

    }

    private boolean isServicesOk() {

        GoogleApiAvailability googleApi = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

        int result= googleApi.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            return true;
        }else if(googleApi.isUserResolvableError(result)){
            Dialog dialog=googleApi.getErrorDialog(this,result,PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR_CODE, task->
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Dialog is cancelled by User", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            dialog.show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Play services are required by this application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void showMarker(double lat, double lng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent =new Intent(MapsActivity.this,Upload_New_Product.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void getCurrentLocation() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Location location = task.getResult();

                    assert location != null;
                    Log.d(TAG,"Map 2 , "+String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+ location.getLongitude());

                    LATITUDE =location.getLatitude();
                    LONGITUDE =location.getLongitude();
                    gotoLocation(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE);
                    showMarker(LATITUDE,LONGITUDE);
                    //  LocationEditText.setText(MyLat+","+MyLong);
                    // geoCoder(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentLocation: Error: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Can't get Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.CurrentLocation) {

            initGoogleMap();


        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }

    private boolean isGPSEnabled() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean providerEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (providerEnabled) {
            return true;
        } else {

            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("GPS Permissions")
                    .setMessage("GPS is required for accessing the Shop location. Please enable GPS.")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", ((dialogInterface, i) -> {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, GPS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define what is precisely for you? Like how many meters or what is your goal on precission?

Comment: @MateoHervas the most precise it can be 5 to 10 meters

Comment: Getting a location has nothing to do with Google Maps or any other map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getLastLocation() doesn't activate location update therefore may not return latest location of the device, you have to call requestLocationUpdates() and setup callback to receive fresh location updates.

Comment: Actually I don't want to receive location updates constantly I want to get the current location once and upload it